# Google Drive Command Line script created 200gigs of log files in 1 night What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

I have been having issues with my drive only syncing when i exit and restart the process. So I wrote a 2 line command line script to run every 15 minutes to restart the drive. After running it for about 12 hours 240gigs of temp files that are located under my user profile in windows under AppData and in the Temp folder were generated. Here is the script that I ran. I dont really understand anything about the files that were generated. Would like to know if theres a better way to force restart google drive so that is syncs. Any help would be appreciated

```
import os, time, sys, subprocess

os.system('taskkill /F /IM googledrivesync.exe')
time.sleep(10)
subprocess.Popen('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Drive/googledrivesync.exe')
sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like "taskkill" is stopping the googledrivesync.exe process without letting it shutdown properly because you have /F in there.

So if you start one of these up and it creates temp files, they never get removed since you're killing the task instead of shutting it down properly.

Try using `taskkill /IM googledrivesync.exe` instead.

Reference:
https://superuser.com/questions/727724/properly-close-not-kill-programs-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks for the response! What would be a better way to shutdown the process through command line?

Comment: I just looked it up, and taskkill /IM is how to do it. This sends a close message to the program. Maybe googledrivesync isn't handling the close message properly.

Comment: Is there someway to delete the temp file when it is created?

Comment: That's a different question. A quick search of google or SO should reveal the answer to that part.

Comment: FWIW, googledrivesync does not (as of 2016-04-27) allow itself to be closed without /F.